# Extract Specific Value from SOAP Response using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, soap

I need to extract the Patient ID (PATAA000000040) from the below SOAP response using JavaScript and insert into Mirth destination. The value is under livingSubjectId tag. This tag might repeat, but we need to take the first livingSubjectId iteration value.

How can I write the JavaScript?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope
    xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <S:Body>
        <ns3:RespondingGateway_PRPA_IN201306UV02Response
            xmlns="urn:gov:hhs:fha:NwHINc:common:NwHINccommon"
            xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
            xmlns:ns3="urn:hl7-org:v3"
            xmlns:ns4="urn:gov:hhs:fha:NwHINc:common:patientcorrelationfacade">
            <ns3:communityResponse>
                <ns3:PRPA_IN201306UV02 ITSVersion="XML_1.0" nullFlavor="">
                    <ns3:id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.609.20.330.002" extension="245c45ce:137cd5bcb6d:-7f4d"/>
                    <ns3:creationTime value="201268183250"/>
                    <ns3:interactionId root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.6" extension="PRPA_IN201306UV02"/>
                    <ns3:processingCode code="P"/>
                    <ns3:processingModeCode code="T"/>
                    <ns3:acceptAckCode code="NE"/>
                    <ns3:receiver typeCode="RCV">
                        <ns3:device classCode="DEV" determinerCode="INSTANCE">
                            <ns3:id/>
                            <ns3:asAgent classCode="AGNT">
                                <ns3:representedOrganization classCode="ORG" determinerCode="INSTANCE">
                                    <ns3:id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.609.10.330.000"/>
                                </ns3:representedOrganization>
                            </ns3:asAgent>
                        </ns3:device>
                    </ns3:receiver>
                    <ns3:sender typeCode="SND">
                        <ns3:device classCode="DEV" determinerCode="INSTANCE">
                            <ns3:id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.609.10.330.002"/>
                            <ns3:asAgent classCode="AGNT">
                                <ns3:representedOrganization classCode="ORG" determinerCode="INSTANCE">
                                    <ns3:id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.609.10.330.002"/>
                                </ns3:representedOrganization>
                            </ns3:asAgent>
                        </ns3:device>
                    </ns3:sender>
                    <ns3:acknowledgement>
                        <ns3:typeId root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.6" extension="PRPA_IN201305UV02"/>
                        <ns3:typeCode code="AA"/>
                        <ns3:targetMessage xsi:nil="true"
                            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                        </ns3:acknowledgement>
                        <ns3:controlActProcess nullFlavor="" classCode="CACT" moodCode="EVN">
                            <ns3:code code="PRPA_TE201306UV" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.1.6"/>
                            <ns3:authorOrPerformer nullFlavor="" typeCode="AUT">
                                <ns3:assignedDevice classCode="ASSIGNED">
                                    <ns3:id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.609.20.330.002.1"/>
                                </ns3:assignedDevice>
                            </ns3:authorOrPerformer>
                            <ns3:subject typeCode="SUBJ">
                                <ns3:registrationEvent classCode="REG" moodCode="EVN">
                                    <ns3:id nullFlavor="NA"/>
                                    <ns3:statusCode code="active"/>
                                    <ns3:subject1 typeCode="SBJ">
                                        <ns3:patient classCode="PAT">
                                            <ns3:id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.609.20.330.002.1" extension="PATAA002000040"/>
                                            <ns3:statusCode code="SD"/>
                                            <ns3:patientPerson classCode="PSN" determinerCode="INSTANCE">
                                                <ns3:name>
                                                    <ns3:family partType="FAM">LastName40</ns3:family>
                                                    <ns3:given partType="GIV">FirstName40</ns3:given>
                                                    <ns3:given partType="GIV">MN40</ns3:given>
                                                </ns3:name>
                                                <ns3:telecom value="tel:+1-417-831-1475"/>
                                                <ns3:administrativeGenderCode code="M"/>
                                                <ns3:birthTime value="19350213"/>
                                                <ns3:addr>
                                                    <ns3:streetAddressLine>225 E Commercial St</ns3:streetAddressLine>
                                                    <ns3:city>Springfield</ns3:city>
                                                    <ns3:state>MO</ns3:state>
                                                    <ns3:postalCode>65803</ns3:postalCode>
                                                </ns3:addr>
                                                <ns3:asOtherIDs classCode="SD">
                                                    <ns3:id root="2.16.840.1.113883.4.1" extension="990000040"/>
                                                    <ns3:scopingOrganization classCode="ORG" determinerCode="INSTANCE">
                                                        <ns3:id root="2.16.840.1.113883.4.1"/>
                                                    </ns3:scopingOrganization>
                                                </ns3:asOtherIDs>
                                            </ns3:patientPerson>
                                            <ns3:providerOrganization classCode="ORG" determinerCode="INSTANCE">
                                                <ns3:id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.609.20.330.002.1"/>
                                                <ns3:contactParty xsi:nil="true"
                                                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                                                </ns3:providerOrganization>
                                                <ns3:subjectOf1>
                                                    <ns3:queryMatchObservation classCode="CASE" moodCode="EVN">
                                                        <ns3:code code="IHE_PDQ"/>
                                                        <ns3:value xsi:type="ns3:INT" value="100"
                                                            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                                                        </ns3:queryMatchObservation>
                                                    </ns3:subjectOf1>
                                                </ns3:patient>
                                            </ns3:subject1>
                                            <ns3:custodian typeCode="CST">
                                                <ns3:assignedEntity classCode="ASSIGNED">
                                                    <ns3:id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.609.20.330.002.1"/>
                                                    <ns3:code code="NotHealthDataLocator" codeSystem="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.2.27.2"/>
                                                </ns3:assignedEntity>
                                            </ns3:custodian>
                                        </ns3:registrationEvent>
                                    </ns3:subject>
                                    <ns3:subject typeCode="SUBJ">
                                        <ns3:registrationEvent classCode="REG" moodCode="EVN">
                                            <ns3:id nullFlavor="NA"/>
                                            <ns3:statusCode code="active"/>
                                            <ns3:subject1 typeCode="SBJ">
                                                <ns3:patient classCode="PAT">
                                                    <ns3:id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.609.20.330.002.2" extension="PATAA002000040"/>
                                                    <ns3:statusCode code="SD"/>
                                                    <ns3:patientPerson classCode="PSN" determinerCode="INSTANCE">
                                                        <ns3:name>
                                                            <ns3:family partType="FAM">LastName40</ns3:family>
                                                            <ns3:given partType="GIV">FirstName40</ns3:given>
                                                            <ns3:given partType="GIV">MN40</ns3:given>
                                                        </ns3:name>
                                                        <ns3:telecom value="tel:+1-417-831-1475"/>
                                                        <ns3:administrativeGenderCode code="M"/>
                                                        <ns3:birthTime value="19350213"/>
                                                        <ns3:addr>
                                                            <ns3:streetAddressLine>225 E Commercial St</ns3:streetAddressLine>
                                                            <ns3:city>Springfield</ns3:city>
                                                            <ns3:state>MO</ns3:state>
                                                            <ns3:postalCode>65803</ns3:postalCode>
                                                        </ns3:addr>
                                                        <ns3:asOtherIDs classCode="SD">
                                                            <ns3:id root="2.16.840.1.113883.4.1" extension="990000040"/>
                                                            <ns3:scopingOrganization classCode="ORG" determinerCode="INSTANCE">
                                                                <ns3:id root="2.16.840.1.113883.4.1"/>
                                                            </ns3:scopingOrganization>
                                                        </ns3:asOtherIDs>
                                                    </ns3:patientPerson>
                                                    <ns3:providerOrganization classCode="ORG" determinerCode="INSTANCE">
                                                        <ns3:id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.609.20.330.002.2"/>
                                                        <ns3:contactParty xsi:nil="true"
                                                            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                                                        </ns3:providerOrganization>
                                                        <ns3:subjectOf1>
                                                            <ns3:queryMatchObservation classCode="CASE" moodCode="EVN">
                                                                <ns3:code code="IHE_PDQ"/>
                                                                <ns3:value xsi:type="ns3:INT" value="100"
                                                                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                                                                </ns3:queryMatchObservation>
                                                            </ns3:subjectOf1>
                                                        </ns3:patient>
                                                    </ns3:subject1>
                                                    <ns3:custodian typeCode="CST">
                                                        <ns3:assignedEntity classCode="ASSIGNED">
                                                            <ns3:id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.609.20.330.002.2"/>
                                                            <ns3:code code="NotHealthDataLocator" codeSystem="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.2.27.2"/>
                                                        </ns3:assignedEntity>
                                                    </ns3:custodian>
                                                </ns3:registrationEvent>
                                            </ns3:subject>
                                            <ns3:queryAck>
                                                <ns3:queryId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.609.10.330.000" extension="-abd3453dcd24wkkks545"/>
                                                <ns3:queryResponseCode code="OK"/>
                                            </ns3:queryAck>
                                            <ns3:queryByParameter>
                                                <ns3:queryId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.609.10.330.000" extension="-abd3453dcd24wkkks545"/>
                                                <ns3:statusCode code="new"/>
                                                <ns3:responseModalityCode code="R"/>
                                                <ns3:responsePriorityCode code="I"/>
                                                <ns3:parameterList>
                                                    <ns3:livingSubjectAdministrativeGender>
                                                        <ns3:value code="M"/>
                                                        <ns3:semanticsText representation="TXT"/>
                                                    </ns3:livingSubjectAdministrativeGender>
                                                    <ns3:livingSubjectBirthTime>
                                                        <ns3:value value="19350213"/>
                                                        <ns3:semanticsText representation="TXT"/>
                                                    </ns3:livingSubjectBirthTime>
                                                    <ns3:livingSubjectId>
                                                        <ns3:value root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.609.20.330.000" extension="PATAA000000040"/>
                                                        <ns3:semanticsText representation="TXT"/>
                                                    </ns3:livingSubjectId>
                                                    <ns3:livingSubjectId>
                                                        <ns3:value root="2.16.840.1.113883.4.1" extension=""/>
                                                        <ns3:semanticsText representation="TXT"/>
                                                    </ns3:livingSubjectId>
                                                    <ns3:livingSubjectName>
                                                        <ns3:value>
                                                            <ns3:prefix partType="PFX"/>
                                                            <ns3:given partType="GIV">FirstName40</ns3:given>
                                                            <ns3:given partType="GIV"/>
                                                            <ns3:family partType="FAM">LastName40</ns3:family>
                                                            <ns3:suffix partType="PFX"/>
                                                        </ns3:value>
                                                        <ns3:semanticsText representation="TXT"/>
                                                    </ns3:livingSubjectName>
                                                    <ns3:patientAddress>
                                                        <ns3:value/>
                                                    </ns3:patientAddress>
                                                    <ns3:patientTelecom>
                                                        <ns3:value value=""/>
                                                        <ns3:semanticsText representation="TXT"/>
                                                    </ns3:patientTelecom>
                                                </ns3:parameterList>
                                            </ns3:queryByParameter>
                                        </ns3:controlActProcess>
                                    </ns3:PRPA_IN201306UV02>
                                    <ns3:NwHINTargetCommunity>
                                        <homeCommunity>
                                            <homeCommunityId>2.16.840.1.113883.3.609.10.330.002</homeCommunityId>
                                        </homeCommunity>
                                    </ns3:NwHINTargetCommunity>
                                </ns3:communityResponse>
                            </ns3:RespondingGateway_PRPA_IN201306UV02Response>
                        </S:Body>
                    </S:Envelope>
```

This is what I tried:

```
msg = new XML(msg);
logger.info(msg);
var soap = new Namespace('http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope');
var edeia = new Namespace('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing');
var PatientID = msg.soap::Body.edeia::controlActProcess.edeia::queryByParameter.edeia::livingSubjectId.toString();
logger.info(PatientID);
channelMap.put('PatientID',PatientID);
```

But got the below error in Mirth:

```
Transformer error
ERROR MESSAGE: Error evaluating transformer
com.mirth.connect.server.MirthJavascriptTransformerException: 
CHANNEL:    Test SOAP Response
CONNECTOR:  sourceConnector
SCRIPT SOURCE:  
SOURCE CODE:    
39:         }
40:         eval('importPackage(' + Packages.java.lang.Class.forName(className).getPackage().getName() + ')');
41:     }
42: }
43: function doScript() {
44: msg = new XML(connectorMessage.getTransformedData());
45: if (msg.namespace('') != undefined) { default xml namespace = msg.namespace(''); } else { default xml namespace = ''; }
46: function doFilter() { phase[0] = 'filter'; return true; }function doTransform() { phase[0] = 'transformer'; logger = Packages.org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(phase[0]);
47: 
48: 
LINE NUMBER:    44
DETAILS:    TypeError: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
    at a2b07c33-e451-4e76-9a96-81c0fdf80552:44 (doScript)
    at a2b07c33-e451-4e76-9a96-81c0fdf80552:79
    at com.mirth.connect.server.transformers.JavaScriptFilterTransformer$FilterTransformerTask.doCall(JavaScriptFilterTransformer.java:154)
    at com.mirth.connect.server.transformers.JavaScriptFilterTransformer$FilterTransformerTask.doCall(JavaScriptFilterTransformer.java:119)
    at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptTask.call(JavaScriptTask.java:113)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What have you tried? This site is great at helping you improve your solution but not very good at doing it all for you!

Comment: Thank you Rob for your response. This is what I tried and got error too. I am trying to learn this part and would really appreciate if you can help me how to proceed with this:msg = new XML(msg);
logger.info(msg);
var soap = new Namespace('http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope');
var edeia = new Namespace('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing');
var PatientID = msg.soap::Body.edeia::controlActProcess.edeia::queryByParameter.edeia::livingSubjectId.toString();
logger.info(PatientID);
channelMap.put('PatientID',PatientID);

Comment: Add this to your question and, if you got an error, show what the error was and where it happened.

Comment: Updated with the error and Javascript which I tried.

Comment: Below is teh updated Javascript:var x= msg.*::['Body'].*::['RespondingGateway_PRPA_IN201306UV02Response'].*::['communityResponse'].*::['PRPA_IN201306UV02'].*::['controlActProcess'].*::['queryByParameter'].*::['parameterList'].*::['livingSubjectId'][0].*::['value']['@extension'].toString();
channelMap.put("PatientId",x);
logger.info(x);

Getting x= PATAA000000040

Let me know if there are any other shortcut or if the above is wrong in any angle…

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not parsing the XML tag correctly, that's what the error says.I was getting a SOAP response like this.

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://test.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://test.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<S:Body>
<ns1:addInformation xmlns:ns2="http://Getdatawebservice/">;
<send>
<MrnNumber>MRN5023150</MrnNumber>
<isError>True</isError>
<ErrorReason>Patient deceased</ErrorReason>
</send>
</ns1:addInformation>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Below is the code that I used to fetch the ***ErrorReason*** tag detail from the response message. I wrote this code in the **Edit Response** tab in the destination.

```
//Replace : completely, mirth somehow not takes it
var updateMsg= new XML (msg).toString().replace(/:/g,”)
    //Create a new XML using it
    var newMsg= new XML (updateMsg);
    //Get the specific Error Reason XML tag value
    var checkError = newmsg[‘SBody’][‘ns1addInformation ‘][‘send’][‘isError’].toString();
    // Not required in your scenario
    if(checkError==”false”)
    {
    var errorMessage = “Message Sent Successfully”;
    channelMap.put(“errorMessage”,errorMessage);
    }
```

You can use the same above code for parsing your required field as well. It should work. For iteration in your case as you say it might appear multiple times, you have to do the looping logic.